# .htaccsess rewrite rule for only one page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not familiar with the rewrite rules..

I am trying to get

```
export.php?type=pdf
```

to be able to be

```
export.php/pdf
```

I already have rewrite rules to remove .php from files..

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

so really it would be.

```
export?type=pdf
```

to

```
export/pdf
```

The issue I'm having is how do i go about doing this for JUST the export.php file ? I know its using Reg-ex for the rules, but i don't know enough to make a new rule, i have tried to Google it and find an answer on how to do it, but the issue is I'm not sure what this is called other than ".htaccess rewrite rule"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule after all your rules,

```
# incoming url is neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ $1.php?type=$2 [L]
```

Comment: although seeing this example now i can see how the Rules work and i understand them now :D (I learn faster from seeing examples)

Comment: I am assuming you are using `$_GET['type']` because it is working here.

Comment: yes i am using $_GET and printing out all of it to debug. i tried clearing cache as well.. still cant get it.

Comment: it is rewriting the URL, but not passing the variable though. IE `export/asdfg` does not 403 but `type` is empty

Comment: its also doing this on every page, and not JUST the `export` page

Comment: This rule is right, just place it before all other rules.